# How to deal with all the depraciations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

this may be a little bit of a dump question but how do you handle backwards compatibility facing all the depreciations in iOS6? I'm currently unsure how to handle them myself.

Examples:

`UITextAlignment` is deprecated, but using `NSTextAlignment` will not work on devices using iOS 5 and prior

`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is deprecated as well in favor of `dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:`

So how could/should one maintain compatibility to older iOS versions? Are there ways to test older versions in XCode 4.5 simulator?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all deprecated methods in your code just set the deployment target of you application to iOS 6.0, and compile your code, then you will get a warning for each deprecated method.

In order to solve the deprecation use one of the following:

1-

```
float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue];


    if(systemVersion < 6.0)
    {
        calendarArray = [self.eventStore calendars];
    }
    else
    {
        calendarArray = [self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
    }
```

2- USer `respondToSelecter` method to detect if the object respond to such selector.

Comment: Don't forget to set your deployment target to original value after you detect the deprecated methods and solve them

Comment: Thanks for the tip, looks reasonable. Somehow i've hoped to avoid those conditional checks. But i think it might be nescesary

Comment: @patman You can use preprocessor #if statements in order to avoid the application from having to process the statement. Its a much better way to go about it.

Comment: @RileyE that's true, but i think pretty much the same in terms of code readability. At least for the constants i could imagine to define the new constants in previous versions myself. `#ifndef NSTextAlignment`

Answer (score 0):

You can download older simulator versions. Xcode (local application menu) > Preferences > Downloads > click to install for the needed simulator versions. Available versions: 4.3, 5.0, 5.1

Comment: 4.3 is not available in Mountain Lion, you will need a mac with older Mac OS X for that.

Comment: okay good to know that. just seen some ugly workarounds for that so far!

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the methods you can make use of the `respondToSelector:` method to detect if the *new method* is available, for example:

```
if ([controller respondToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)]) {
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```